# Angular Rails Devise Override Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, authentication, devise

I have an angular repository (grunt serve runs at localhost:9000) and a rails repository (rails server runs at localhost:300). I make a hit at localhost:3000/users/sign_in with user object (email and password).

1. When creds are incorrect, I get the 'login page' in the response.
2. When creds are correct, I get '302' as response code as devise
   directs to actual page.

What I actually want is :

1. When creds are incorrect, return some json to be decoded at angular end which says creds are wrong
2. When creds are correct, send user object and a token which angular keeps and creates session. This token could be used at each request to see the user has a valid login session.

I know I need to override devise controllers and I have copied those to my codebase, but I don't know what should I code specifically inside 'new' and 'create' (specially for that token thing). Do I need to :

- Change my gem from devise to something else ?
- Change my logic/expectations on angular side ?
- Any other specific suggestions

Thanks in advance !